# Non-generator elements of a group and Intersection of all maximal subgroups.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

A [non-generator element](http://www.google.lk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CBwQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FGenerating_set_of_a_group&ei=XfEcVYytF9Xc8AW5w4GIBQ&usg=AFQjCNGH_9ZVMjkN56vK8ynXV2EAxl0alA) $u$  of a group $G$ is defined as,

> If $H\not=G,$ then $\langle H,u\rangle\not=G$ for any $H\le G.$

Show that set of all non-generators of $G$ is a subgroup of the intersection of all [maximal subgroups](http://www.google.lk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CC4QFjAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FMaximal_subgroup&ei=rPEcVfeiBs_t8gW29IH4BA&usg=AFQjCNEo8_IZpaNS5O6N-FrsoJxgA6Zytg) of G.

I have no idea to attempt this question.
Any idea to start an answer? Thank You.

Comment: Can u please give the source of the problem or the book from where you have collected this ;I am in search of a problem book

Comment: It's a standard result in lots of books. Try searching for Frattini Subgroup.

Comment: Thank you. I found it in Wikipedia [Frattini Subgroup.](http://www.google.lk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&sqi=2&ved=0CBwQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FFrattini_subgroup&ei=-ElMVZ_GDseyuQT_jYHoCQ&usg=AFQjCNER3Gv3NRoy_CWmUCMT9Bn7vvza3g&bvm=bv.92765956,d.c2E)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if $H$ is any maximal subgroup and $u$ is a nongenerator, then we must have:
$$
<H,u> = H
$$
this follows directly from the definitions, since if $<H,u>$ properly contained $H$ it must be equal to $G$ (by maximality of $H$), and this is ruled out by the fact that $u$ is a non-generator.

but $H$ was an arbitrarily-chosen maximal subgroup, so $u$ must be in the intersection of all maximal subgroups.

Comment: Well done @David

Comment: You should also mention other direction.

Comment: @mesel the OP does not ask about that, but i agree with you that the answer would have been improved by mentioning it. +1 for your useful observation.

Comment: @learnmore thx. i found the idea of the Frattini subgroup puzzling when i first encountered it. realizing that all elements in the additive group of $\mathbb{Q}$ are non-generators was an eye-opener in a small way. yet another property of the infinite which requires adjustment of our naïve intuition

Comment: If $G$ is a finite group, can we show that $$\{\text{set of non-generators}\}=\cap\{\text{Maximal subgroups}\}$$ ?

Answer (score 1):

**David Holden** gave me a wonderful solution. But I think it is better to prove that the set of all non-generators are form a subgroup.

Since $1$ is a non-generator, set of all non-generators is non empty.
Lets take any two non-generators $u_1, u_2$ and a proper subgroup $H$ of $G.$
Then we can see that $$\langle H,u_1u_2^{-1}\rangle\le\langle \langle H,u_1\rangle,u_2\rangle\lt G$$ Hence $u_1u_2^{-1}$ is also a non-generator of $G.$
Therefore set of all non-generators form a subgroup of $G.$

Comment: +1 always good to look at alternative routes to a result!

Comment: What do you think about my above question?

Comment: re your question above, there may be an argument along the lines of: if $a$ is a generator, then there must be a subgroup maximal for the property of not containing $a$

Comment: the case of a single generator is niggling me, perhaps un-necessarily!